# Get last 3 months names in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a report where in the user is only allowed to select an option from last 3 months as shown below :

[image: Month requirement in select]

I want to write a javaScript function to achieve this.

What I tried was :

```
function getLastMonths(n) {

    var months = new Array();

    var today = new Date();
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    var month = today.getMonth() + 1;

    var i = 0;
    do {
        months.push(year + (month > 9 ? "" : "0") + month);
        if(month == 1) {
            month = 12;
            year--;
        } else {
            month--;
        }
        i++;
    } while(i < n);

    return months;

}
```

Then I called the function by passing parameters :

```
document.write(getLastMonths(4));
```

It prints :

```
201704,201703,201702,201701
```

Which is not the pattern I require it in.

Can anyone help me out here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look here. It's a bit shorter thanks to *for loop*

```js
function getLast3Months() {

  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];

  var today = new Date();
  var last3Months = []

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    last3Months.push(monthNames[(today.getMonth() - i)] + ' - ' +today.getFullYear()  );
  }
  return last3Months;
}

document.write(getLast3Months());
```

Comment: This fails when it has to go back to previous year

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43652557/1425210 this is the only perfect answer

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this. Simply go on subtracting `one month` from current date

```js
function getLastMonths(n) {
  var m =['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
  var last_n_months =[]
  var d = new Date()
  for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
    last_n_months[i] = m[d.getMonth()]+ ' - ' + d.getFullYear().toString()
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth()-1)
  }
  return last_n_months
}
console.log(getLastMonths(3))
```

Comment: your answer is almost the same as mine but returns 5 months and not 3 like asked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this . add month name into some `array` then find the index

```js
function getLastMonths(n) {
var m =['','Jan','Feb','Mar','Aprl','May','Jun','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
  var months = new Array();

  var today = new Date();
  var year = today.getFullYear();
  var month = today.getMonth()+1;

  var i = 0;
  do {
    months.push( m[parseInt((month > 9 ? "" : "0") + month)]+'-'+year);
    if (month == 1) {
      month = 12;
      year--;
    } else {
      month--;
    }
    i++;
  } while (i < n);

  return months;

}
document.write(getLastMonths(4));
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the number to the name manually due to internal JS names not being public.

See below for working example. This outputs exactly how you shown the months in the dropdown.

```js
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
function getLastMonths(n) {

    var months = new Array();

    var today = new Date();
    var year = today.getFullYear();
    var month = today.getMonth() + 1;

    var i = 0;
    do {
        months.push(monthNames[month] + ' - ' + year);
        if(month == 1) {
            month = 12;
            year--;
        } else {
            month--;
        }
        i++;
    } while(i < n);

    return months;

}

document.write(getLastMonths(4));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using moment.js?

```js
var getLastMonths = function(n) {
  var arr = new Array();

  arr.push(moment().format('YYYY MM'));

  for(var i=1; i< 3; i++){
    arr.push(moment().add(i*-1, 'Month').format('YYYY MM'));
  }
  
  return arr;
}

var appendOptions = function(arr) {
  var html = '';
  
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    html += '<option value="' + arr[i] + '">' + arr[i] + '</option>'  
  }

  document.getElementById('select-months').innerHTML = html;

}

var months = getLastMonths(4);
appendOptions(months);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<select id="select-months"></select>
```

Comment: or use the full angular framework ... a bit strange to propose a library for something easy as this

Comment: @VikingCode Why you think it is strange? I'm deeply interested in your opinion.

Comment: a lib is a set of tools, usually a big set of tools (read file) that you import in to your project to make your code less complicated and encapsulate functionality in correct software tire. But in this case, importing a lib has no extra value. You can write shorter code in vanilla js, and spare your project from extra dependency that you don't have to manage.

Comment: @VikingCode Thanks to you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the earlier code and given one example:
fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/asutosh/rogpxwah/

```
function getLast3Months() {

  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];

  var today = new Date(2019,3,12);
  var month=today.getMonth();
  var last3Months = []

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      var newMonth=(today.getMonth() - i);
      var newYear=today.getFullYear();

      monthInWords=monthNames[newMonth];
      if(newMonth<0){

       newYear=today.getFullYear() - 1;
       monthInWords=monthNames[12+newMonth];
      }
     var newDate= new Date(today.getDate(), newMonth, newYear);
     last3Months.push(monthInWords + ' - ' +newYear  );
  }
  return last3Months;
}

window.document.write(getLast3Months());
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a Node 12+, ES2020 Generator method in less than ~5 junctions of code...

```js
function* lastMonths(start = 0, end = 4, step = 1, D = new Date()) {
  const o = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US" , { month: "long", year: "numeric" })
  for (let i = start; i < end; i += step) {
    const past = new Date(D)
    void past.setMonth(D.getMonth() - i)
    const localeStr = o.format(past).replace(' ', ' - ')
    yield localeStr
  }
  return D
}
console.log([...lastMonths()])
```

> [ "July - 2021",
> "June - 2021",
> "May - 2021",
> "April - 2021" ]

Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators